# R/S designation

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is my answer wrong ? (Tutors answer in blue bubble)

[image]

OH is highest priority, the carbon groups are second highest priority, H is lowest priority

Answer (score 1):

So you need to distinguish between the carbon groups.

Let direction A be through the central bond and direction B be through the terminal phenyl or methyl group for either chiral center. If you look *two positions* away from the carbon you're evaluating, you see the second hydroxyl oxygen (which I suspect you missed) along direction A but only carbon and hydrogen atoms along direction B, so direction A is #2 behind the direct hydroxyl connection.